# finding sum of a column with specific values of a column in SQL using group by

Tags: sql, group-by, sum

I have a table with the following columns:

```
amount   employee   
100        a
200        a
300        b
400        b
500        c
```

I want to get an output in the same table which groups based on employee 'a' and the rest (other than a ) and gives the sum of the amount, based on grouping.
Desired result :

```
amount  employee 
300            a 
1200         rest
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert the employee values using CASE WHEN and group the converted value:

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN employee = 'a' THEN 'a' ELSE 'rest' END as e,
  SUM(amount) as a
FROM
  t
GROUP BY
  CASE WHEN employee = 'a' THEN 'a' ELSE 'rest' END
```

You could also use UNION:

```
SELECT 
  MAX(emlpoyee) as e,
  SUM(amount) as a
FROM
  t
WHERE employee = 'a'

UNION ALL

SELECT 
  'rest' as e,
  SUM(amount) as a
FROM
  t
WHERE employee <> 'a'
```

This latter way will probably be more resource intensive but may be easier to understand and maintain hence you need to make a judgement as to whether you value outright performance or developer friendliness. (For a query run once a day on a hundred employees you could argue that having the query be easier to understand would be better. For a query hitting tens of thousands of employees a second, performance should take precedence )

Comment: Thank you for response but it is giving me multiple values of a and rest like a 300 is present multiple times   in output and rest 1200 multiple times. How can I fix that?

Comment: for the union code != is throwing an error is there any other not function can be used?

Comment: Take it again; i fixed a bug with it, sorry

Comment: Can I know why we are using max(employee)?

Comment: Otherwise you get an error because it's not grouped. The query selects only employee `a` so max will be `a` always. You could say `SELECT employee, SUM... FROM t WHERE employee = 'a' GROUP BY employee`, you could say `SELECT 'a' as emp, SUM ... WHERE employee = 'a'` to not have a group by, but then you have to put `'a'` twice into the query, or you can put employee into a MAX which will allow the query to work also, and you dont have to put 'a' twice, nor write GROUP BY - different ways to achieve the same end result

Comment: It won't make any difference in this case

Answer (score 0):

Use a `case` expression for the `group by` key:

```
select (case when employee = 'a' then employee else 'rest' end) as employee,
       sum(amount)
from t
group by (case when employee = 'a' then employee else 'rest' end) ;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=98ab77e3fff044208c347b1e2bf44311) is a db<>fiddle.  (This happens to use MySQL, but this is standard SQL and will work in any database.)

Comment: Hi Gordon, I am getting repeated outputs in table like this a   300                                                                                                                   a   300                                                                                                                  a  300                                                                                                                  rest 1200                                                                       rest 1200

Comment: @taashu there's something you haven't told us then, because this query works as you requested (as does my similar version); you've made some mistake integrating it into the rest of your system

Answer (score 0):

Please use below query,

```
select sum(amount), employee from
(select 
amount, case when employee = 'a' then employee else 'Rest' end as employee
from table t) t1
group by employee;
```